# printing opcode to asm format

Tags: c++

I have a shellcode that gets changed in my program,

I then want to be able to print it, to check if everything is right.

How would i print it so it is readable in the way i have set my vector.

```
std::vector<unsigned char> shellcode  = {
    0xB8, 0x00 ,0x00, 0x00, 0x00,   //mov eax, 0
    0xFF, 0x30,                     //push [eax]
    0xFF, 0x70, 0x04,               //push [eax+4]
    0xFF, 0x70, 0x08,               //push [eax+8]
};

printf("Opcode generated:");
for (int i = 0; i < shellcode.size(); i++) {
    printf(" 0x%02x", (unsigned char)(shellcode[i] & 0xFF));
}
```

should be a shorter way then this

```
printf("Opcode generated:\n");
for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    printf(" 0x%02X", shellcode[i]);
}
printf("\n");
for (int i = 5; i <= 6; i++) {
    printf(" 0x%02X", shellcode[i]);
}
printf("\n");
for (int i = 7; i <= 9; i++) {
    printf(" 0x%02X", shellcode[i]);
}
printf("\n");
for (int i = 10; i <= 12; i++) {
    printf(" 0x%02X", shellcode[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to create an `std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>>` and use range-for loop to print the values.

Here's a working example ([live](https://godbolt.org/z/Exg3gD)):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>> shellcode  = {
        { 0xB8, 0x00 ,0x00, 0x00, 0x00 },   //mov eax, 0
        { 0xFF, 0x30 },                     //push [eax]
        { 0xFF, 0x70, 0x04 },               //push [eax+4]
        { 0xFF, 0x70, 0x08 },               //push [eax+8]
    };

    printf("Opcode generated:\n");
    for (  const auto& row : shellcode )
    {
        for ( const auto& byte : row )
        {
            printf(" 0x%02X", byte);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Opcode generated:
 0xB8 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
 0xFF 0x30
 0xFF 0x70 0x04
 0xFF 0x70 0x08
```

Another solution could be to maintain line lengths like this ([live](https://godbolt.org/z/t8oGHa)):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    const std::vector<unsigned char> shellcode
    {
        0xB8, 0x00 ,0x00, 0x00, 0x00,   //mov eax, 0
        0xFF, 0x30,                     //push [eax]
        0xFF, 0x70, 0x04,               //push [eax+4]
        0xFF, 0x70, 0x08,               //push [eax+8]
    };

    const auto lineLengths = { 5, 2, 3, 3 };

    printf("Opcode generated:\n");
    auto index {0u};
    for ( auto lineLength : lineLengths )
    {
        while ( lineLength-- )
        {
            printf(" 0x%02X", shellcode[index++]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can add an assertion before going into the loop for printing that the size of `shellcode` must be equal to the sum of of `lineLengths`. Something like this:

```
#include <numeric>
#include <cassert>
assert( std::accumulate(lineLengths.begin(), lineLengths.end(), 0) == shellcode.size() );
```

Here's the live example with the assertion: https://godbolt.org/z/n5B-42

Comment: Problem is that may affect my `WriteProcessMemory(hProc, pCode, shellcode.data(), dwCodeSize, nullptr)` call

Comment: @werico4026: So, you are directly passing it as-is to this function?

Comment: No i add more to it, just showed some of it for a example

Comment: @werico4026: You have to maintain the lengths somehow. See my updated answer. You can use a separate container for lengths and combine with code to print it in a loop.